# Insertion Sort using Binary Search in matlab...causing error "Out of memory. The likely cause is an infinite recursion within the program."

Tags: matlab

I am currently working on comparing the time complexity of Insertion Sort using linear search compared to using binary search to sort backwards in the "i" while loop A[1...(i-1)]. I keep getting errors in matlab stating:

unsorted_array =

```
86    63    36    52    41     8    24    13    19    24
```

current j: 2
current i: 1
current low: 1
current high: 1
current mid: 1
current low: 1
current high: 0
current mid: 0
Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Error in INSERTION_SORT>BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE (line 34)
if(key == A(mid))

Error in INSERTION_SORT>BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE (line 40)
z = BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE(A,key,low,mid-1);

Error in INSERTION_SORT>INSERTION_SORT_BINARY_SEARCH (line
51)
insertionIndex = BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE(A,key,1,i);

Error in INSERTION_SORT (line 5)
sorted_array_using_binary_search =
INSERTION_SORT_BINARY_SEARCH(unsorted_array)

I do not see my error. The BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE function never returns either "low" or "low+1" like it should. I am going through the matlab tutorial again to see if I'm making an error in the syntax. I can't figure this out and could appreciate some help and finding exactly what mistake I'm making. The code is below:

```
%unsorted_array = randi([1,100],1,10)
unsorted_array = [86    63    36    52    41     8    24    13    19    24]

%sorted_array_using_linear_search = INSERTION_SORT_LINEAR_SEARCH(unsorted_array)
sorted_array_using_binary_search = INSERTION_SORT_BINARY_SEARCH(unsorted_array)


function [y] = INSERTION_SORT_LINEAR_SEARCH(A)
    n = length(A);
    for j = 2 : n
        temp=A(j);
        i = j - 1;
        while ((i > 0) && (A(i) > temp))
            A(i+1) = A(i);
            i = i - 1;
        end
        A(i + 1) = temp;
    end
    y = A;
end

function [z] = BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE(A,key,low,high)
    if(high <= low)
        if(key > A(low))
            z = (low + 1);
        else
            z = low;
        end
    end
    disp("current low: " + low)
    disp("current high: " + high)
    mid = floor((low + high)/2);
    disp("current mid: " + mid)
    if(key == A(mid))
        z = mid+1;
    end
    if(key > A(mid))
        z = BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE(A,key,mid+1,high);
    else
        z = BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE(A,key,low,mid-1);
    end
end

function [x] = INSERTION_SORT_BINARY_SEARCH(A)
    n = length(A);
    for j = 2 : n
        key = A(j);
        i = j - 1;
        disp("current j: " + j)
        disp("current i: " + i)
        insertionIndex = BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE(A,key,1,i);
        while (i >= insertionIndex)
            A(i+1) = A(i);
            i = i - 1;
        end
        A(i+1) = key;
    end
    x = A
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't you return from the function once you've found `z`?

Comment: I don't understand. Can't I just say "z = (index value determined)" for the return, which is either "low" or "low+1"? Or I just say "z = BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE(values in arguments)"? I'm thinking your right. I just don't know the right syntax to do it maybe?

Comment: Setting `z = low` simply sets the value. The program flow continues beyond the `if` clause and executes the code below it. I haven't looked closely at the logic, but that looked suspect to me. The syntax for [`returning from a function`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html) is pretty simple.

Comment: You are right beaker! The function works now!  I don't know how I missed that small thing.

Answer (score 0):

"beaker" was right (in the comments above). I need to set the value of z = (whichever index low or low+1) and then put return after I set "z". The code works and is down below:

```
%unsorted_array = randi([1,100],1,10)
unsorted_array = [86    63    36    52    41     8    24    13    19    24]

sorted_array_using_linear_search = INSERTION_SORT_LINEAR_SEARCH(unsorted_array)
sorted_array_using_binary_search = INSERTION_SORT_BINARY_SEARCH(unsorted_array)


function y = INSERTION_SORT_LINEAR_SEARCH(A)
    n = length(A);
    for j = 2 : n
        temp=A(j);
        i = j - 1;
        while ((i > 0) && (A(i) > temp))
            A(i+1) = A(i);
            i = i - 1;
        end
        A(i + 1) = temp;
    end
    y = A;
end

function z = BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE(A,key,low,high)
    if(high <= low)
        disp("first if executed")
        if(key > A(low))
            disp("second if executed")
            z = (low + 1);
            return
        else
            disp("first else executed")
            z = low;
            return
        end
    end
    disp("current low: " + low)
    disp("current high: " + high)
    mid = floor((low + high)/2);
    disp("current mid: " + mid)
    if(key == A(mid))
        z = (mid + 1);
    end
    if(key > A(mid))
        z = BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE(A,key,mid+1,high);
    else
        z = BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE(A,key,low,mid-1);
    end
end

function x = INSERTION_SORT_BINARY_SEARCH(A)
    n = length(A);
    for j = 2 : n
        key = A(j);
        i = j - 1;
        disp("current j: " + j)
        disp("current i: " + i)
        insertionIndex = BINARY_SEARCH_RECURSIVE(A,key,1,i);
        while (i >= insertionIndex)
            A(i+1) = A(i);
            i = i - 1;
        end
        A(i+1) = key;
    end
    x = A
end
```